# Initialize a minesweeper in c

Tags: c, initialization, minesweeper

I'm currently rewriting a minesweeper program in C using the CSFML library.

I'm having some issues at managing the initialization only after the first click, more precisely in the part where I'm supposed to set the tiles around the click empty.

I can't find a way to make these tiles empty without having a risk of removing some bombs. 
Here's my init code block for now :

```
int current = 0;

    temp.bombs = BOMB_EASY;
    temp.difficulty = EASY;
    temp.mapEasy = malloc(sizeof(sTILE *) * (Y_EASY + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < Y_EASY + 1 ; i++)
    {
        temp.mapEasy[i] = malloc(sizeof(sTILE) * (X_EASY + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < X_EASY + 1; i++)
    {
        temp.mapEasy[Y_EASY][i].type = 0;
    }

    while (current < BOMB_EASY)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Y_EASY; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < X_EASY; j++)
            {
                int isBomb = rand() % 10;
                if (isBomb == 0 && current < BOMB_EASY && temp.mapEasy[i][j].type != 9)
                {
                    temp.mapEasy[i][j].type = 9;
                    current++;
                }
                else if (temp.mapEasy[i][j].type != 9)
                {
                    temp.mapEasy[i][j].type = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Y_EASY; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < X_EASY; j++)
        {
            if (temp.mapEasy[i][j].type == 0)
            {
                temp.mapEasy[i][j].type = HowManyBombs(temp.mapEasy, i, j, Y_EASY, X_EASY);
            }
            temp.mapEasy[i][j].isRevealed = sfFalse;
            temp.mapEasy[i][j].isFlagged = sfFalse;
        }
    }
}
```

I know my question might seem stupid and someone probably already answered it but I couldn't find the answer so thanks at the ones who will answer me.

Comment: Your `while` loop will run forever if you are unlucky, i.e. if the `rand() % 10` doesn't return `0` enough times. You should run `current` from `0` to `BOMB_EASY`, and use `rand()` to determine the coordinates for the bomb. Also couple of remarks:1) Why do your variables have the `_EASY` suffix? 2) You allocate the matrix to `(Y_EASY + 1)*(X_EASY + 1)`, but you only index it up to `[Y_EASY][X_EASY]`, why is that?

Comment: To answer your questions Groo : 

1) My variables have the _EASY suffix because I have other difficulties stored in other arrays because I didn't found a way to use a single array for all the difficulties.

2) I allocate at one unit over the limit to avoid segmentation fault errors or stack overflows and by that avoid the array filling go outside my board, but it's not really necessary I admit.

And thank you for your advice I haven't thought to do it this way, I'll try it on right now.

Comment: I presumed that this might be the case, but this indicates that you have different functions for different difficulty levels, which is unnecessary. These values should be parameters to your functions, because the algorithm should work the same regardless of the board size or the bomb count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an empty matrix
2. Fill it with *n* mines at random locations. Upon generating (x, y) coordinates, check if they are already taken.
3. If the coordinates are already taken, you should place the mine at the next available position.

   For example by increasing x by 1, check if free, if not, increase x again. Upon reaching the end of the row, increase y instead and start over with x=0.

   If you simply generate a new random number, your algorithm could in theory get forever stuck. In practice it will probably work, but I would expect such an algorithm to generate the grid slower<sup>1)</sup> than one that just picks the next free spot.

---

<sup>1)</sup> rand() call overhead is the most likely bottleneck in this algorithm. But also if you pick the next spot rather than calling rand() again, the CPU might be able to speculatively load (parts of) the array in prefetch data cache. This wouldn't be possible when the memory location is literally random each time you pick it.